# Restore to existing partition layout with Todo Backup or other software?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, restore, easeus-todo-backup

I used EaseUs Todo Backup to backup and recover several computers. Every computer has only one disk. In a few cases one had an already existing partition layout as follows: 1. Windows7 boot partition (100MB), 2. System partition (50GB), 3. Data partition (200GB).

My original backup contained a clean Windows 7 system with the first small boot partition, and a 40GB system partition. I tried many times to restore that in a way that I could keep the third, data partition untouched, and restore the backup only to the first two partitions. I had no success at all. Every time in the restore procedure I am prompted with the screen that shows that my data partition will be lost, and I will have a system partition with 250GB size, so the new system partition swallows the existing data partition.

I had no luck with their support so far either.

EDIT: To clarify the problem:

This is the disk/partition backup layout:

```
[x][xxxxxxxx----------------]
```

This is the target disk layout before restore:

```
[x][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx------][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx----------------------------]
```

This is what I would like after I restore the backup to the target disk (restored data marked with capital X):

```
[X][XXXXXXXX----------------][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx----------------------------]
```

This is what I get with Todo Backup, no matter what options I try to use:

```
[X][XXXXXXXX--------------------------------------------------------------]
```

If Todo Backup cannot solve this, is there an alternate solution?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What you want isn't possible with the software your using.

Comment: It is hard to understand what exactly do you want. Could you make you question more clear?

Comment: I added some example about what I'd like to achieve, the question should be clearer now. Hope you have any idea, or any other suggested software with this feature.